# xcode5 'Expected Expression' error

Tags: c, express, xcode5

I almost finished to build a project when this code gave me an error:

```
    struct dyld_all_image_infos *dyldaii;
mach_msg_type_number_t size = sizeof(dyld_all_image_infos);
vm_offset_t readMem;
kern_return_t kr = vm_read(task, address, size, &readMem, &size);
if (kr != KERN_SUCCESS)
{
    return;
}

***dyldaii = (dyld_all_image_infos) readMem;***
int imageCount = dyldaii->infoArrayCount;
mach_msg_type_number_t dataCnt = imageCount * 24;
struct dyld_image_info *g_dii = NULL;
```

The line `dyldaii = (dyld_all_image_infos) readMem;` is giving me an error "expected expression". What would be needed to complete or fix this phrase?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: You're saying you want a pointer to a structure from the kernel, then you try to *cast that pointer* to the structure without dereferencing it. This cannot work.

Comment: The thing is called `struct dyld_all_image_infos`, not `dyld_all_image_infos`.

Comment: Thanks's a lot for the responses! Ill be sure to change this!